# What is an example of normalizing the state in a React Redux app?

Tags: reactjs, redux, state, react-redux

I'm reading the Redux Reducers [docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html) and don't get how normalizing the state would work. The current state in the example is this:

```
{
  visibilityFilter: 'SHOW_ALL',
  todos: [
    {
      text: 'Consider using Redux',
      completed: true,
    },
    {
      text: 'Keep all state in a single tree',
      completed: false
    }
  ]
}
```

Can you provide an example of what the above would look like if we followed the below?

> For
>   example, keeping todosById: { id -> todo } and todos: array inside
>   the state would be a better idea in a real app, but we’re keeping the
>   example simple.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This example is straight from [Normalizr](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr).

```
[{
  id: 1,
  title: 'Some Article',
  author: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Dan'
  }
}, {
  id: 2,
  title: 'Other Article',
  author: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Dan'
  }
}]
```

Can be normalized this way-

```
{
  result: [1, 2],
  entities: {
    articles: {
      1: {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Some Article',
        author: 1
      },
      2: {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Other Article',
        author: 1
      }
    },
    users: {
      1: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Dan'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**What's the advantage of normalization?**

You get to extract the exact part of your state tree that you want.

For instance- You have an array of objects containing information about the articles. If you want to select a particular object from that array, you'll have to iterate through entire array. Worst case is that the desired object is not present in the array. To overcome this, we normalize the data.

To normalize the data, store the unique identifiers of each object in a separate array. Let's call that array as `results`.

`result: [1, 2, 3 ..]`

And transform the array of objects into an object with keys as the `id`(See the  second snippet). Call that object as `entities`.

Ultimately, to access the object with `id` 1, simply do this- `entities.articles["1"]`.

Comment: why is the result array still needed? to me, normalization just changes the data structure from an array to a hash for faster lookup, but it's still nested. I don't see how it's flat

Comment: @mangocaptain You can go one level deep and normalize that data too! The array is needed to reproduce original array of objects. For eg. `results.map(id => entities.articles[id])` will return original array of objects. That is one use-case for the separate array.

Comment: @mangocaptain If the user wishes to delete some of the elements from the UI, simply delete those elements from the `results` array. That will trigger a re-render in React. While re-rendering, `results.map(id => entities.articles[id‌​])` will produce the updated data. Forgive me, if I'm not making any sense to you. But you'll understand better if you build some example projects using React+Redux.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [normalizr](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr) for this.

Normalizr takes JSON and a schema and replaces nested entities with their IDs, gathering all entities in dictionaries.

For example,

```
[{
  id: 1,
  title: 'Some Article',
  author: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Dan'
  }
}, {
  id: 2,
  title: 'Other Article',
  author: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Dan'
  }
}]
```

can be normalized to

```
{
  result: [1, 2],
  entities: {
    articles: {
      1: {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Some Article',
        author: 1
      },
      2: {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Other Article',
        author: 1
      }
    },
    users: {
      1: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Dan'
      }
    }
  }
}
```